# Attempting to make a prepared statement with ODBTP (Linux -> MSSQL)

Tags: sql-server-2008, prepared-statement

I am attempting to connect to my SQL SERVER 2008 database using Ubuntu Linux and ODBTP to run a prepared statement and insert a new row into the database.

The query looks like the following

```
$Q = "INSERT INTO Table
       ([DocumentGuid]
       ,[ProjectId]
       ,[CreatedByContactId]
       ,[IdNumber]
       ,[Type])
        VALUES
       (:DocumentGuid
       ,:ProjectId
       ,:CreatedByContactId
       ,:IdNumber
       ,:Type )";

$statement = odbtp_prepare($Q , $database_connection);

// Attach the values to the procedure. 
odbtp_attach_param($statement,":DocumentGuid",$DocumentGuid,ODB_CHAR);
odbtp_attach_param($statement,":ProjectId","33",ODB_INT);
odbtp_attach_param($statement,":CreatedByContactId","5",ODB_INT);
odbtp_attach_param($statement,":IdNumber","ID",ODB_CHAR);
odbtp_attach_param($statement,":Type","ABC",ODB_CHAR);

odbtp_execute($statement);
```

But I am getting the following error message in the log
"PHP Warning:  [ODBTPERR][0]Not prepared procedure in (filename) on line 14"... Line 14 being the first odbtp_attach_param() line.

I have only ever made prepared statements using PDO and I am probably doing something wrong.

does anyone have an example prepared statement created using ODBTP they could show me?

Comment: what is on line number 288 ?

Comment: what is this before edit it was line number 288 now it is line number 14 ?

Comment: Yes the error was on line 288 in my code. I edited it to line 14 of the example in the code above for clarity. Probably should have specified that.